# Van Kampen's Theorem: how to find the value of $N$ in $\pi_1 (S^2,x_0) = \frac{e * e }{N}$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Van Kampen 's  Theorem :

> Let  $X=  A_1 \cup A_2$,where  $A_1 ,A_2 $  and  $A_1 \cap A_2 $   are path  connected   and let $x_0  \in  A_1\cap A_2 $ then $\pi_1 (X,x_0) = \frac{\pi_1(A_1) * \pi_1(A_2) }{N}$

> where  $N$ is the  smallest  normal  subgroup  generated   by the  elements  $[(j_1i_1)_*(w)]*[(j_2i_2)_*(w)]^{-1}$ where     $w\in \pi_1(A_1 \cap A_2)$

Compute  $\pi_1(S^2)$

My attempt :-  $A_1=S^2\setminus \{n\} $ and $A_2=S^2\setminus\{s\} $ where  $n$ and  $s$  denote  the north  and  south poles  respectively

$\pi_1(A_1)=\pi_1(A_2)=  \{e\}$

$\pi_1(A_1 \cap A_2)= \mathbb{Z}$

By  Van Kampen's thorem $\pi_1 (S^2,x_0) = \frac{e * e }{N}$

**My   question** : How  to find  the value of $N$ ?

**My attempt** :we know that $N$ is the  smallest  normal  subgroup  generated   by the  elements  $[(j_1i_1)_*(w)]*[(j_2i_2)_*(w)]^{-1}$ where     $w\in \pi_1(A_1 \cap A_2)$

Here
$(i_1)_*:\pi_1(A_1\cap  A_2)  \to  \pi_1(A_1)$

$(i_2)_*:\pi_1(A_1\cap  A_2)  \to  \pi_1(A_2)$

$(j_1)_*:\pi_1(A_1)  \to  \pi_1(A_1 \cup A_2)$

$(j_2)_*:\pi_1(A_2)  \to  \pi_1(A_1 \cup A_2)$

$\implies  [(j_1i_1)_*(w)]*[(j_2i_2)_*(w)]^{-1}= [j_1(\pi_1(A_1))(\mathbb{Z})]*[j_2(\pi_1(A_2))(\mathbb{Z})]^{-1}$

After that im  not able to proceed  further

Comment: Can you identify the group `e*e` with something more familiar? `N` must be a subgroup; what are the possibilities?

Comment: @JohnPalmieri $ \{e\}  * \{e\}= \{e\}  $.

Comment: okay,, $N=\{e\} $ is the only subgroup of $\{e\}$@JohnPalmieri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $e * e$ is the trivial group, so the only possibility for $N$ is the trivial group.  This is the fastest way to identify $N$ from van Kampen's theorem and your set-up.

For some more insight, look at what the maps $i_1$ and $i_2$ do: they map from $\pi_1(A_1 \cap A_2)$ to $\pi_1(A_1)$ and $\pi_1(A_2)$ respectively.  You correctly identified the isomorphism types of all these groups, so you can tell $i_1$ and $i_2$ are homomorphisms from an infinite cyclic group to the trivial group.  Therefore must both be the trivial homomorphism.  What this means geometrically is that any path in $A_1 \cap A_2$ (which has the homotopy type of the circle) becomes nullhomotopic when viewed as a path in either $A_1$ or $A_2$, which are simply connected.